# Mosaico refusing to run on upgrade

Tags: mosaico

I am running CiviCRM version 5.43.0 on Wordpress 5.8.2 with PHP 7.4 - it's a new site, freshly installed.

We had Mosaico running (though in fact at the time I think we didn't have either GD or php-ImageMagick installed!) via the CiviCRM Extensions manager. FLexmailer, GD and php-ImageMagick are all now installed (for both PHP 8, and for 7.4).

On upgrade to 2.8, Mosaico is now generating errors.  When opening CiviCRM, a modal appears:

> Mosaico: Packages are missing Mosaico requires dependencies in its
> "packages" folder. Please consult the README.md for current
> installation instructions.

And if you go to Mailing > New Mailing a message appears:

> Mosaico cannot be displayed because this system does not meet all requirements.

I have the CiviCRM log viewer extension installed, and this is not showing any errors.  Google searches don't return anything obvious.  I'd appreciate any assistance in debugging this error further - should I be asking this on Mosaico's boards instead? Many thanks!

Tried so far:

- Install phpImageMagick
- Install GD
- Clear CiviCRM Caches
- Server reboot (never hurts hey)

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix this by uninstalling the Extension in the CiviCRM manager, then deleting the uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico folder from the extensions folder, and then reinstalling via the Extensions Manager

Comment: I tried this fix, but it deleted all the custom templates I had created. It seems like this is only a fix if you haven't made any tweaks to Mosaico.